# Error not all code paths return a value. why?

Tags: c#, return-value

```
public static trnUser GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) == true)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to return something if the condition is false.

Comment: The `if` statement implicitely checks your condition versus `true`, hence the manual `== true` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) == true) {
      return null;
} else {
      return new trnUser();
}
```

you need to provide information on what to return when the if statement is false.

Comment: Since there's a `return` in the `if` statement, there is no need for the `else`.  you can just do `return new trnUsr();` after the `}`